# Is there an API to get binary downloads for Eclipse packages?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to automate Eclipse installation.

For JDKs for example, I can get the download links via https://api.adoptopenjdk.net/q/swagger-ui/

The Eclipse download button contains a link with a mirror id, and then that page triggers a download. Unfortunately it's not a clean redirect that could be followed with curl/wget. I can observe the final download URL with a proxy like Fiddler, but that is not a stable solution.

```
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2021-03/R/eclipse-java-2021-03-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg&mirror_id=1190
```

Or, if no API exists, is there another somewhat stable URL to download Eclipse binaries from programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **`&r=1`** to the URL for the direct **file/binary download** link, for example:

- Use mirror #1190: [`https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2021-03/R/eclipse-java-2021-03-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg&mirror_id=1190&r=1`](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2021-03/R/eclipse-java-2021-03-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg&mirror_id=1190&r=1)
- Best mirror (without `mirror_id=...`): [`https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2021-03/R/eclipse-java-2021-03-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg&r=1`](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2021-03/R/eclipse-java-2021-03-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg&r=1)
- Download from eclipse.org (mirror_id=1): [`https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2021-03/R/eclipse-java-2021-03-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg&mirror_id=1&r=1`](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2021-03/R/eclipse-java-2021-03-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg&mirror_id=1&r=1)

These are **stable** links as long as the files have not been archived.

See also:

- [Eclipse Wiki - IT Infrastructure Doc - Use mirror sites/see which mirrors are mirroring my files?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/IT_Infrastructure_Doc#Use_mirror_sites.2Fsee_which_mirrors_are_mirroring_my_files.3F)
- [PHP code of `download.php`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/www.eclipse.org/downloads.git/tree/download.php)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This is not documented anywhere, right?

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/IT_Infrastructure_Doc#Use_mirror_sites.2Fsee_which_mirrors_are_mirroring_my_files.3F and by the [public PHP code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/www.eclipse.org/downloads.git/tree/download.php) ;)